# How do I return a chart from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function `tickets_ages()` calculates how many tickets each age group bought for an event.

I need to create a visual representation to show ticket sales for every age group, but I cant figure out how to do it. I got the fundamentals done, the function just outputs every age group + the number of tickets sold.

**The Calculation**: Function takes largest number, in this case 18 and divides it by 4, which is 4.5. The 4.5 will represent one tick mark on the chart `*`

for the rest of the numbers, each number is divided by 4.5, same as the largest division factor of 18.

```
0 to 20: 12 ---> becomes 2.66
20 to 40: 15 ---> becomes 3.33
40 to 60: 16 ---> becomes 3.55
60 to 80: 15 ---> becomes 3.33
80 and over: 18 ---> 4.5
```

This is my code:

```
def sort_list(value):
    sorted_v = list(set(value)) #This just puts the values once so they dont repeat, dont worry about it
    sorted_v.sort()
    return sorted_v


'''
The list
'''
ages = ['0 to 20', '0 to 20', '0 to 20', '0 to 20','0 to 20', '0 to 20', '0 to 20', '0 to 20','0 to 20', '0 to 20', '0 to 20', '0 to 20', '20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','20 to 40','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','40 to 60','60 to 80','60 to 80','60 to 80','60 to 80','60 to 80','60 to 80', '40 to 60','60 to 80','60 to 80', '80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','80 and over','40 to 60','60 to 80','60 to 80','60 to 80','60 to 80','60 to 80','60 to 80', '40 to 60','60 to 80','80 and over'] 

'''
Main function
'''
def tickets_ages(ages):
    sort_thelist = sort_list(ages)
    string_s = ''
    for source in sort_thelist:
        output = ages.count(source)        
        string_s += '{}: {} \n'.format(source, output)
    return string_s    

'''
Test code
'''

print(tickets_ages(ages))
```

output should be:

```
0 to 20: ***  #---> 2.66
20 to 40: *** #---> 3.33
40 to 60: *** #---> 3.55
60 to 80: *** #---> 3.33
80 and over: ***** #---> 4.5
```

Comment: Hint: `'*' * 10` → `'**********'`

Comment: @martineau Yes, I know, my main problem is I don't know how to do that exclusively for each specific age group, and get the largest number of the age groups, divide that by 4 and the rest by 4.5, if you could give me a hint on how to do it that would be great!

Comment: I was hinting to answer the titular question — how to make a chart.To do those other things, I would suggest storing the number in each age group in some type of container, like a list or dictionary. You could then easily do all those other things you're now asking about down here in the comment. Python's built-in container data-structures are one of it primary strengths — try to make better use of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb do not return formatted output from a function if you are planning to process it further. Modify your function to return the raw results:

```
def tickets_ages(ages):
    sort_thelist = sort_list(ages)
    output = []
    for source in sort_thelist:
        output.append((source, ages.count(source)))
    return output
```

Then process the output to calculate the "tick" value (i.e. 4.5 in your example):

```
results = tickets_ages(ages)
tickets = list(zip(*results))[1]
tick = max(tickets) / 4
```

You can now print your results using this information:

```
for age, ticket in results:
    score = round(ticket / tick, 2)
    stars = '*' * round(score)
    print(f"{age}: {score}: {stars}")
print()
```

This should print:

```
0 to 20: 2.67: ***
20 to 40: 3.33: ***
40 to 60: 3.56: ****
60 to 80: 3.33: ***
80 and over: 4.0: ****
```

The `score` value is included for demonstration purposes, you can remove it from the f-string if you don't need it.

Edit: If you want to modify your original function to return the chart instead:

```
def tickets_ages(ages):
    sort_thelist = sort_list(ages)
    results = []
    output = ""
    for source in sort_thelist:
        results.append((source, ages.count(source)))
    tickets = list(zip(*results))[1]
    tick = max(tickets) / 4
    for age, ticket in results:
        score = round(ticket / tick, 2)
        stars = '*' * round(score)
        output += f"{age}: {score}: {stars}\n"
    return output

print(tickets_ages(ages))
```

Comment: I suggest you to make it a separate function (e.g. `generate_chart`) and feed the output of the first function into the new one.

Comment: Yes, you can simply append to a string instead of using a print statement (like you did in your original code) and do it in one function, even though it is not the best practice.